# How to calculate mean average of dates using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, graph, count, statistics

I have a system that captures attendance data, which gets stored in the database with name of the person and the date of attendance. What the system has to do is to calculate the average of attendance and represent that data in the form graph.

Can someone please help on this one.

Comment: What do you mean "average attendance"? You can't take "average" from a date. You mean eg. how long was he working, or what time usually he comes to the office, or...?

Comment: Well isn't that easy to do: `((count(array_dates_attendance)) / count(array_working_dates)) * 100` this will give you a percentage.

Comment: what i mean is the system has to count the attendace rate based on the dates and then displace the occurance in a chart

Comment: by rate do you mean: no. of students attended on a particular date/total number of students and display these rate on a date basis

Comment: yes bigRG that is what i mean

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you have a database that records in a table the couples (name,date of attendance)

What you need to do is just count how many times each date appears. It can be done in several ways, either on the MySQL side or the PHP side.

Example with MySQL:

```
SELECT date,COUNT(*)  
FROM attendance       
GROUP BY date;
```

You will get something like:

```
"July 1", 18
"July 8", 22
"July 15", 16
```

If you want an average, this should work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date,COUNT(*) FROM attendance GROUP BY date;");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{   
    $attendance[] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
}  
$average = array_sum($attendance) / count($attendance);
```